# Can you set a contact's image in AddressBook programmatically on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'd like to be able to set a contact's default image programmatically on the iPhone. Does the API currently allow for that? I've found you can toggle several properties for the person, and create new contacts. I can't seem to find anywhere in the documentation that allows to set a photo.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ABPersonSetImageData](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABPersonRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/ABPersonSetImageData) is what you are looking for.